# Problem with std::partition to seperate elements less than pivot

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, partition

So I was implementing quicksort where I used std::partition for getting partition index but it isnt working as expected 
Here's Code

```
int l=10;
srand(time(NULL));
vector<int> arr(l,int());
generate(arr.begin(),arr.end(),[](){return rand()%100;});
int p=arr.back();
copy(arr.begin(),arr.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
cout<<"Index:"<< distance( begin( arr ), partition(begin(arr), end(arr), [&p](int m){ return m<p;}) );
copy(arr.begin(),arr.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
```

Here's Screenshot of Output
[SR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOBQt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of

```
cout<<"Index:"<<*partition(begin(arr), end(arr), [&p](int m){ return m<p;});
```

you mean

```
cout<<"Index:"<< std::distance( std::begin( arr ), partition(begin(arr), end(arr), [&p](int m){ return m<p;}) );
```

That is you need to calculate the distance between the pointer to the first element of the array and the pointer to the element where partitioning ends.

Comment: oops yeah but still this isnt partitioning as expected,I tried std::stable_partition too but still aint working

Comment: @ShantanuVerma It is unclear what you mean by "is not partitioning as expected".

Comment: elements should be seperated according to lesser or greater than value p but it isnt working

Comment: @ShantanuVerma No, it works. See your own output. All elements are less than 47 in the first part of the array nefore the elememt with the value 56.

Comment: @ShantanuVerma Again the first four elements are less than the last element of the array. So the array is partitioned according to your condition. What is the problem?!

Comment: oops i thought the value at index i am getting is the value according to which it partitioned.Thanks!

Comment: @ShantanuVerma You can swap the pointed value with the value of the last element that was used to partition the array.